# How to see the daemon process's output in Linux?

Tags: linux, tty

I wrote a test.c:

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    while(1)
    {
        sleep(1);
        printf("====test====\r\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

then i compile it : gcc ./test.c -o ./test
and the i wrote a shell script:

```
#!/bin/sh
./test &
```

and then i made this script to be executed automatically on system boot.
then I login to the Linux system using secureCRT in SSH protocol.
using "ps aux | grep test" i can see the test process running,
but i just cannot see the test's output, some people told me because the test
output to tty, and i am using pts.
could anybody tell me the specific reason and how can i get the output?
thanks in advance!

Comment: FYI, don't use `test` as it's the name of a shell function

Comment: Why do you write a shell script which does nothing but calling another application?

Comment: Exactly how do you start your "daemon"? A true daemon doesn't write to stdout (or stderr, or read from stdin), because it isn't attached to a console. The normal behaviour is to write to a logfile.

Comment: you have to redirect the output (stderr and stdout) to a file. BTW, just adding & after the name of a program call through a shell doesn't make a daemon. Have a look at `fork`, `setsid`, etc.

Comment: thanks ,i read the chapter in APUE, NOW I know more about daemon process!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It doesn't output anything because it got no terminal attached.

If you want your output to be visible to every terminal connected to the system, use `wall`

```
./test | wall
```

*(it will be very annoying)*

I suggest you to redirect the output to a log file.